# File ID different from the URL File ID - Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access a file in a Google Drive directory but linking to it using the File Id provided by the API it says that i don't have permission. What i saw is that the File Id in the URL is different from the one who returns from the API. Why?

Using the test page of the Google Api it returns a "Not Found" error(404) and not the "No Permissions" error. Anybody knows how to get this ID(same of the url) that links to the file instead of the File's ID

Edit: Found that the File Resource has a property called "webViewLink" is it the link to the file instead of using the ID?

Comment: The file in the URL is not always the file id in the api.   Do a file.list in the api to list all the files you have access to.  webViewLink will give you a link to the file but again you will only be able to see the file if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying the Drive API, you can set using ***fields*** property what values you want to return from your call as it is shown in this image:
[image]

- ***webViewLink*** will return you the link that's shown when you open the file in your browser.
- ***id*** will return you the ID of the file.

I specified some values, but you can see [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) all the values you could use and if you put **"*"** you will return all of them. Also, I didn't show in the image the id of the file to not share that info.

[HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid) you can see why you are getting that error. Surely,  you don't have enough permitions because you have already checked that it exists for what I understood in your question.